# I don't want to use Data::Dumper's default settings, what can I do?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I find myself using this method to print out Perl values all the time:

```
sub d {
  Data::Dumper->new([])->Terse(1)->Indent(0)->Values([$_[0]])->Dump;
}

say "x = ", d($x), ' y = ', d($y);
```

I like this because I don't want `$VAR1 =` in my output, and I rarely deal with recursive data structures.

But the thought of creating a new `Data::Dumper` object and performing that long chain of  initializations every time I call `d()` bothers me.

Is there another stringifier I can use?

Answer (score 5):

Option 1, use the [`Data::Dumper` variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods):

```
$Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;

say Dumper "x =", Dumper($x), " y = ", Dumper($y);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that modifies the settings for everybody else.

Comment: use `local` to set them. eg `{ local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; say Dumper($x); }`

Answer (score 5):

```
sub d {
  use feature 'state';

  state $dd = Data::Dumper->new([])->Terse(1)->Indent(0);
  return $dd->Values(shift)->Dump;
}
```

Untested, but something like this should work.

Comment: Yeah - I've done that. I also clear out `Values` so that the dumper object doesn't keep references to the last thing you dumped.

Answer (score 4):

I tried [`Data::Dump`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDump) and never looked back.

```
use Data::Dump 'dump';

dump $structure;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Data::Dumper::Concise](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper-Concise/) is handy. Not the same settings as you require, but possibly good for someone else. `Sortkeys` in particular is essential

From the documentation:

```
Data::Dumper::Concise;
warn Dumper($var);
```

is equivalent to:

```
use Data::Dumper;
{
  local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Quotekeys = 0;
  local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
  warn Dumper($var);
}
```